# SSIS XML Multiple Outputs Into 1 DB Table

Tags: xml, ssis

I have a SSIS package set up through Visual Studio that process a flattened (through XSLT) XML file. When I process the XML file in the data flow, it creates 17 different outputs. None of these outputs has a foreign key that I can relate the tables with. Is there anyway to combine all these tables into one output, or a process that pulls all data from the XML file into one table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to use native XML you can use 'Merge Join' shapes to bring the data back together. The MergeJoin requires that the begin sorted. So you end up with a lot of Sort and MergeJoin shapes. But it truely works out of the box. The c# solution using xsd.exe is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is limited in how it can handle XML and for a complicated XML feed I would recommend using a Script Component as your source and writing your logic for reading the XML file and creating the desired output using C#.

That would give you the best flexibility for generating an output in the Data Flow that suits the your needs to load it into the destination table of your choice.